# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available

Tags: tomcat6

I have Tomcat 6 when I getting start my server error context start form

```
 SEVERE: Exception processing JAR at resource path /usr/share/java/jakarta-commons-pool-1.3.jar in context
 java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

When I request to any site it displays an error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:527)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:73)
    com.wvmagic.rf.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:73)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:229)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:581)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:73)
    com.wvmagic.rf.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:73)
```

I have tried lot, but cannot resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this file: jasper-jdt.jar. If it doesn't exist in your /lib directory, than you should get one.

Comment: jasper-jdt.jar available at /tomcat/lib

Answer (score 0):

Probably means exactly what it says, you don't have a Java compiler. You need to install a SDK so that it can compile JSPs . Check for Java SDK and don't forget to set JAVA_HOME .

See [this discussion](http://objectmix.com/java/115086-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-java-compiler-available.html)  for troubleshooting your problem.